# How to get city and pincode with ragular expression

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have few address and i want to get pincode and city name in that address through regular expression

These are address

```
M G Road, Dlf City Phase I Gurgaon, Gurgaon - 122001, Near Sikanderpur Metro Station
Plot 32, Central Business District, Shahdara, Delhi - 110032
Sardar Patel Marg, Chanakya Puri, Delhi - 110021, Diplomatic Enclave
Golf Course Road, Gurgaon Sector 56, Gurgaon - 122011, Near Ghata Gaon
```

Look into pincode that is 6 digit only and with it city name

```
    M G Road, Dlf City Phase I Gurgaon, Gurgaon - 122001, Near Sikanderpur Metro Station = Gurgaon - 122001

Plot 32, Central Business District, Shahdara, Delhi - 110032 = Delhi - 110032

Sardar Patel Marg, Chanakya Puri, Delhi - 110021, Diplomatic Enclave = Delhi - 110021

Golf Course Road, Gurgaon Sector 56, Gurgaon - 122011, Near Ghata Gaon = Gurgaon - 122011
```

How can i get it? even there is coma also but it in random order some time it's come in front and some time in middle and in last. but there must be 6 digit pincode number and , - also there.

Please help me to find out the result

Comment: look for a 5 digit number instead?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like homework / OP did not put the minimum effort in exploring how to sole this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
▶ addr = %q|M G Road, Dlf City Phase I Gurgaon, Gurgaon - 122001, Near Sikanderpur Metro Station
▷ Plot 32, Central Business District, Shahdara, Delhi - 110032
▷ Sardar Patel Marg, Chanakya Puri, Delhi - 110021, Diplomatic Enclave
▷ Golf Course Road, Gurgaon Sector 56, Gurgaon - 122011, Near Ghata Gaon|
▶ addr.scan(/(\w+\s+-\s+\d+)(?=,|$)/).flatten
#⇒ [
#  [0] "Gurgaon - 122001",
#  [1] "Delhi - 110032",
#  [2] "Delhi - 110021",
#  [3] "Gurgaon - 122011"
# ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following.

```
text =<<-END
M G Road, Dlf City Phase I Gurgaon, Gurgaon - 122001, Near Sikanderpur Metro Station
Plot 32, Central Business District, Shahdara, New Delhi - 110032
Sardar Patel Marg, Chanakya Puri, Delhi - 110021, Diplomatic Enclave
Golf Course Road, Gurgaon Sector 56, Gurgaon - 122011, Near Ghata Gaon
END

r = /
    (?<=,)     # Match a comma in a positive lookbehind
    (?:        # Begin a non-capture group
    \s+        # Match >= 1 whitespace characters
    [A-Z]      # Match a capital letter
    [a-z]+     # Match >= 1 lowercase letters
    )          # Close non-capture group
    +          # Match group >= 1 times (e.g., 2 for "New Delhi")
    \s+        # Match >= 1 spaces
    -          # Match a hyphen
    \s+        # Match >= 1 spaces
    \d{6}      # Match six digits
    (?=[\D\z]) # Match a non-digit or end of string in a positive lookahead
    /x         # Regex extended mode

text.lines.map { |s| s[r].strip.split(/\s-\s/) }
  #=> [["Gurgaon", "122001"], ["New Delhi", "110032"],
  #    ["Delhi", "110021"], ["Gurgaon", "122011"]]
```

Comment: Thanks to describe all these :)

Comment: Did you use a tool to generate the annotated regex, or did you do it by hand? It looks really nice...

Comment: @Brad, the only tool I used was a keyboard. Your question has me wondering, however, if there might be a gem that does that.

Comment: Cool - thanks. http://www.regexbuddy.com/ kinda does something like that, but not with the nice formatting. I was hoping there might be an even better alternate...